# I keep getting "No Internet Connection" on Windows 10 from time to time, but I have no problems on Linux Fedora

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a problem with my Internet connection. From time to time, I can't connect to any website (due to a timeout), and I get the "No Internet Connection" error and the warning sign near the Wi-Fi taskbar icon. When I reconnect, everything works fine again, but only for some time. There is no specific time interval between losing the connection. Sometimes it may work the whole day without interruptions (rather seldom, though), and sometimes it disconnects every several minutes.

I get this problem only on my Windows 10 1607 (build 14393.3630), Broadcom 802.11.n network adapter. But if I use Linux Fedora (from a Live CD) everything works absolutely fine, so there are no hardware problems.

I reinstalled the driver as @John suggested, but alas it didn't help. How can I fix this issue?

Here is the list of the installed Windows Updates:
[image]

**Note:** Please, don't mark this question as a duplicate. I've been [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1288515/windows-10-losing-internet-connection), but the given answer and comment didn't help me, because:
1) The last driver version is installed, but I can't downgrade it, because I haven't updated it.

2) I also don't want to use another Wi-Fi adapter or a wired connection

3) I use WPA2, not WEP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107327/discussion-between-cfcbazar-com-and-demian-wolf).

Comment: @demian-wolf I know it has been a while, but I just posted an answer on a similar topic that might help you or others that come looking for an answer. See https://superuser.com/a/1634196/235052

Comment: @JoaoLeme thank you! :) I remember I have *not* tried the steps from your answer, so they might have helped me at the time. Now, I switched to Linux Fedora, so I don't use Windows at all. But I am sure that other Windows users will find your answer useful. +1 for the comment and the answer.